# Export an Eclipse RCP product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

When I try to export my own RCP product I receive this error:

```
 In plugin com.nex.editor, the value for property source.lib/commons-beanutils.jar is not set.
```

Any help or idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: So, where's the questionable code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have `source.lib/commons-beanutils.jar` in a `build.properties` that is syntaxically incorrect.
Search for that string in your workspace and check every `build.properties`